# Resize images in WordPress using its URL

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need to resize some images in some of my posts. I can get the image URL stored in postmeta created using the [Types plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/types/).
So using postmeta I can get the URL, but how to resize the images of a specific post type?

Comment: Do You need to re-size Your images in some of your posts or you need to create some format to create posts with the standard custom image size in it?

Comment: re-size image in some of  posts

Comment: Have you tried using inline style in `img` tag of your post? I think you are aware that wordpress has html view in post submission form in admin panel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you have to find attached image id from image URL. To get attached image id from image URL add below function in your theme `functions.php` file:

```
function pn_get_attachment_id_from_url( $attachment_url = '' ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $attachment_id = false;

    // If there is no url, return.
    if ('' == $attachment_url)
        return;

    // Get the upload directory paths
    $upload_dir_paths = wp_upload_dir();

    // Make sure the upload path base directory exists in the attachment URL, to verify that we're working with a media library image
    if (false !== strpos($attachment_url, $upload_dir_paths['baseurl'])) {

        // If this is the URL of an auto-generated thumbnail, get the URL of the original image
        $attachment_url = preg_replace('/-\d+x\d+(?=\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$)/i', '', $attachment_url);

        // Remove the upload path base directory from the attachment URL
        $attachment_url = str_replace($upload_dir_paths['baseurl'] . '/', '', $attachment_url);

        // Finally, run a custom database query to get the attachment ID from the modified attachment URL
        $attachment_id = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT wposts.ID FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id AND wpostmeta.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file' AND wpostmeta.meta_value = '%s' AND wposts.post_type = 'attachment'", $attachment_url));
    }

    return $attachment_id;
}
```

For more information read see url - https://philipnewcomer.net/2012/11/get-the-attachment-id-from-an-image-url-in-wordpress/

Then we need to use image resize function in `function.php`:

```
add_image_size( 'latestproperty_thumb', 370,293,true );
```

To get the image attachment id use:

```
$attachid = pn_get_attachment_id_from_url($url);
```

After this install https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/. Then go to Tools->Regenerate thumbnail and regenerate all thumbnails.

After that use this to get the regenerated image url:

```
$src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachid, 'latestproperty_thumb');
```